# Date formating with Character field

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

I have a character field that represents the date as `'01-JAN-13'`.  When I reformat with `TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, 1, 9),'YYYY-MM-DD')`, I get the result as `13-JAN-01`.

How to get the data in format `YY-MM-DD`. Do I need to write in a CASE to change the month to numbers?

```
SELECT dsis_cc_master.created_ts
     , to_date(substr(dsis_cc_master.created_ts, 1, 9), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS created_month
  FROM traffic_eng.dsis_cc_master
 WHERE dsis_cc_master.created_ts >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

My result is

```
01-JAN-13    13-JAN-01
```

I am trying to get `01-01-13` or `13-01-01` in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting back a date value, which is *displayed* however the client is configured to display dates.  If you want to explicitly set the format use `to_char` to return a character string instead:

```
select 
    DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, 1, 9),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD-MM-YY') as created_month 
FROM TRAFFIC_ENG.DSIS_CC_MASTER
WHERE DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

However you are changing the *return type* which may cause issues if the consumer of this query is *expecting* a date type to come back (e.g. to do date math).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the date format model and `TO_CHAR` function to get the result in the format that you require:

```
select DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, 1, 9),'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DD-MM-YY') as created_month FROM TRAFFIC_ENG.DSIS_CC_MASTER
WHERE DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Since the data in your column is already stored in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you could actually just `substr(DSIS_CC_MASTER.created_ts, 3, 7)` and you'll get what you need.